# Excel 2013 - Is there a way to turn off a chart series without removing it?

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2013

This past year I finally switched to Excel2013 from Lotus123.  The only task I miss from Lotus (that I can't figure out how to do in Excel) is: when formatting charts and creating copies of charts it was easy in Lotus to turn 'on' or turn 'off' a chart series (when formatting for printing the chart).  It seems in Excel I can only add or remove the series permanently.  Is there an easier way to visually turn off and on a chart line series without removing it from the `select data source` menu?

Answer (score 13):

In Excel 2013, when you select a chart, three icons appear floating to the right of the chart. The third of these is the filter icon.

[image: Unfiltered Chart]

Uncheck the box in front of a series and click Apply. The unchecked series will be hidden from the chart. Notice no formatting of other series takes place, because the series isn't removed by hiding any columns of the worksheet; the series is simply filtered out of the chart's view.

[image]

Comment: Is this limited to V.2013?

Comment: Very nice, Jon. Shows the danger of suggesting tips for 2013 when I do most of my work on 2010.

Comment: Yes so i would need my gov.office to upgrade my Excel to version 2013.  At least Microsoft has clarified this need! (previous tips: hiding the columns would not be a solution for me as it would make the series' hidden in all worksheet charts; while the other suggestion of turning the line colour off, excel still displays the series name in the legend..)  My next request if anyone knows for version 2013: Has excel increased the series limits for XY-Scatter charts, to have a series include more the 32000 rows?  In old versions of Lotus123 i would get 60000 rows plotted easily.

Comment: According to https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3, points in an individual series is "Limited by Available Memory".

Answer (score 2):

By default, hiding the data for that series (i.e. hiding the column or row) will hide the series in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

If I want a series to be invisible, I just set its Marker Style to `None` and its Line Color to `No Line`.  If I want to interact with it again, I select it in the 'chart elements' drop-down box in the Ribbon under `Chart Tools > Layout > Current Selection`.

Comment: This is okay except that the legend still has a ghost entry for the series.

Comment: To remove the ghost entry: single left-click on the legend; then single-left click on the ghost entry in the legend; then press Delete (Backspace might also work). It's hack-tastic to the max, but it works.  (Not as well as your recent answer, though!)

Comment: Then if you want the legend entry back when you're done hiding the series, you need to delete the legend, add it back, then redo any other formatting you lost in the process.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, I agree that it's an annoying way to do it. Pre-2013, though, I don't think there's much other attractive option -- it's least-worst.  At least in 2010 (maybe 2007?) you *can* delete the individual legend entries; I think in 2003 one was stuck with the ghost entry.

Comment: No, you've been able to delete individual legend entries since at least Excel 97.

Comment: It's often better to add a label to the data series than to use a legend. It might be easier to hide a label along with hiding its parent series than figuring what to do with the legend.

Comment: No kidding. Wish I'd figured it out sooner!  And yeah, my grad advisor would have knocked me upside the head anyways for even worrying about legends. He's a strong proponent of direct labeling of data series. (In Excel, textbox or data label; he prefers Kaleidagraph for publication-quality figures.)