# Excel How can I visually turn off/on some of the series within a multiple scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

I have a scatter plot with many series in it and for better understanding of  the data, I would like to be able to sort them into categories and select for viewing only some of them to compare the results. (Another option would be to create multiple charts, but the original data is located in multiple files where is updated constantly - so I would like to have everything in one chart and quickly select for viewing some of the series)

Something similar was shown here before [Excel 2013 - Is there a way to turn off a chart series without removing it](https://superuser.com/questions/888900/excel-2013-is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-a-chart-series-without-removing-it) , but I have much more series and I would like in the filter option on the right to be able to group them also. Is that possible? Is there any other possible way to do this? 
I have no experience with VBA but I am also looking for a way to automate this in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without any VBA, conceptually, is:

Plot all data in the chart, format all series gray.

Provide a few cells where the user can select a few series names. 
Use formulas to populate helper cells with the corresponding values of that series. 
Plot the helper cells as additional series in the chart and format them with colors.

The screenshots show this in action with a line chart
[image]

Data preparation on a different sheet with lookup formulas for the red, blue and green series columns.[image]

If you need more details, please pipe up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use an Excel add-in, you can use Front languages and there is an easy way to do this in Javascript.

Here is a working code I have written for you:

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a6a014fee0b8c3283c65451

As you can see by this link, I used an online editor with an embedded spreadsheet to create this chart. The data in the spreadsheet is connected to my code via a JSON file, as such:

```
{
    "data": "=A1:C33"
}
```

I have created three scatter chart series, with a javascript library called [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/):

```
 var trace1 = {
  x: firstX,
  y: firstY,
  mode: 'markers',
};

var trace2 = {
  x: secondX,
  y: secondY,
  mode: 'markers',
};

var trace3 = {
  x: thirdX,
  y: thirdY,
  mode: 'markers',
};
```

With this library, the chart you create has an interactive menu when you pass your mouse above it.

If you click on a serie's label on the right you can remove it visually from the chart:

[image: remove]

click again to make it reappear:

[image: normal]

You can load your chart on Excel by pasting the URL on the [Funfun Excel add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like with my example:

[image: final]

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of Funfun.**